# Excel; after pressing return in a cell, cursors stays in the same position

Tags: excel, vba

After I input some text in a cell and press return, the cursors jumps one cell down like it's supposed to do, then jumps back. I've checked the options /advanced/ editing options, but that's set to move selection "Down". No idea why this is happening but could there be some VBA option causing this?

Thanks
James

Comment: Its possible. If you right click your sheet tab, View - Code, do you have a Select or Change event?

Comment: try to open your file without activating the macros (or save your file in .xlsx if you have 2007+)

Comment: What happens when you set the default behavior to jump one cell to the right? does the cursor jump back to the left (original cell) or up?

Answer (score 0):

Just forgotten to take code out of my worksheet_change method, very annoying! Thanks for your help, turning off the macros was a good start.